# How do I Import/Export models with more primitives than triangles?

Tags: python, export, import, file-format

I'm writing a game engine using pyassimp, which .blend support isn't very good on...

I'd like to know what supported model format I could export to that supports primitives such as quad-strips and polygons.

I know Collada supports all of this, but unfortunately, libraries like pycollada (used by blender) are triangles-only.

Also, I wouldn't mind writing an exporter if anyone knows of a library.
(I've been searching google for months so this is just a shot in the dark)